# Surface Area and Volume Cone Problem

Tags: geometry

The problem goes: What is the ratio of the height of a cone and the radius of it if the volume is at its highest and the surface area is at its lowest.

I'm not even really sure if there is a solution to this, yet a teacher did give it to me so it likely does have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem statement suggests that there is a maximum in the ratio of volume to surface area as function of $h/r$. However, if we look at the volume and surface area of the cone, to wit,

$$
V=\frac{\pi r^2h}{3}\\
S=\pi r \sqrt{r^2+h^2}
$$

and let $x=h/r$ we get

$$
V=\frac{\pi r^3x}{3}\\
S=\pi r^2 \sqrt{1+x^2}\\
\frac{V}{S}=\frac{r}{3}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$$

I appears that $V/S$ is strictly monotonically increasing in terms of $h/r$.